# Validation Curve Interpretation

Tags: python, classification, visualization, cross-validation, training

I have been reading about the `validation_curve` function from scikit learn. When I run this it takes too long. Therefore, I am plotting the results from grid search instead, which seems to be far quicker. However, when I plot using the code from: https://matthewbilyeu.com/blog/2019-02-05/validation-curve-plot-from-gridsearchcv-results.

I get:

[image]

Why are the lines so close together? Shouldn't I get a curve instead? More generally, how can I tell if my model is under-fitting or overfitting? How  can I plot the overfit/under-fit areas on my plot.

edit: i am trying to predict if a client will  default on a loan or not so 1 for yes 0 for no. the data are financials. also the data i have used is about 100k samples

Comment: At first glance it looks like you are using a small dataset that is easy to model. Regardless of the hyperparameters you choose, xgboost easily finds an optimal solution. Cross validated performance is a little lower as you have a few tricky examples that don’t fit the pattern described by the rest of the dataset, and when these are in the hold-out set in cross validation the model performs worse. Could you please describe your dataset and tell us what you are trying to predict?

Comment: thanks i have updated it

Comment: I think we'd need the grid search and parameter space definitions, as well as how you called the blogs function.

Answer (score 0):

You can understand whether your model is overfitting or underfitting  by the difference in the graph of your train and validation score. If your train score(performance not loss) is low and so is val score then your model is underfitting. On the other hand if your model is overfiiting you will have high training accuracy but your validation score will be low and the train and val graph will be far from each other. A perfect model just has high training score with the validation  curve as close as possible and the two graphs will be very close like the graph you provided.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are very few loan defaults in your dataset, so xgboost is learning to predict 0 for all inputs regardless of the hyperparameters you choose. Try sampling from your data so that the classes are more balanced (e.g. >10% of your data points are defaults) and see what happens.

Other options for dealing with highly imbalanced classes can be found here: https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/03/imbalanced-data-classification/